# What is the most efficient way to model this kind of wrought-iron shape?

Tags: modeling

[image: object]

I only care about the sphere and its design, not the bird on top.

This kind of curvy iron design shows up on many Victorian designs and other examples of old-fashioned smithing. How can I efficiently produce a sphere like this? (Also feel free to comment/edit if you know a more precise term for this than just "curvy Victorian ironwork.")

My first idea was to make a wireframe UV sphere, then model the curvy bits separately. Then, if I could somehow snap the curvy bits to the sphere in a way that makes the bits follow the curve of the sphere, I could do something with an Array modifier. However, I don't know how to snap objects that way.

Another example of the "curvy bits" I'm talking about:

[image: more curvy bits]
<sub>(source: [rackcdn.com](http://19d34b5eeb5741888711-087bc10d9f02607843dd2ebc6171c8d6.r30.cf3.rackcdn.com/aldgate-home-FullSizeRender%20%28138%29_main-1_large.jpg))</sub>

Comment: Here's the solution which may help you, but as Gunslinger said, there is no shortcut in this case: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/28198/how-can-i-model-a-spherical-tesselation-such-as-this-one-in-blender

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Looking at what you're wanting to achieve, I think using the [*decimate modifier* >*un-subdivide*](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/modifiers/generate/decimate.html#un-subdivide) with 1 iteration should work well to get you started, and keep a uniform pattern across the model. Hope that helps get you started.[image]

Answer (score 17):

This is no shortcut. But you will have detailed control over your model.

I would start with a highres UVsphere and then add geometry with snap and shrinkwrap to follow the spheres surface.

[image: geometry along sphere surface]

Then add a solidify modifier followed by a subsurface modifier:

[image: with modifiers]

You can apply the solidify modifier and fiddle with the geometry if you want to make it beveled or such.

[image: fiddle with the geometry]

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't accept multiple answers, or else I would have accepted this one too!

Answer (score -1):

[image]

Some assorted ideas.

- Left to Right.
- Start with sphere or cylinder.  Place Ends. Push Pull. Loop Cuts.
- Proportional Editing.
- Curve Modifier. Example Curve in Red.
- Sizing to Curve. More proportional editing
- Modify Twist on Curve.  Consider Shrink Wrap Modifier to sphere for curve only.  Not Mesh.
- You can be more artistic than shown above
- Arrange to sphere not shown