# How do you model this Spherical Hollow Object?

Tags: modeling

Seen this model on a question post. Which brought me to the question
of how do you create this model, in the quickest most effective way
with what blender tools can offer.

[image]

Comment: The process is described in the answer to this question:
http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/44345/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-model-this-kind-of-wrought-iron-shape

Comment: Thanks Somatic, The answer can be found here http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/44345/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-model-this-kind-of-wrought-iron-shape
indeed.

Comment: I would submit that the fact that this question has the same answer as question 44345, that this automatically make them duplicate questions, any more than the question "What color is the top stripe of the US flag?" and the question "What is the color of the international 'NO' symbol?" are duplicates because the answer to both is "red".

Comment: @brasshat I agree with you , but the fact that the answer ( submitted earlier ) fits exactly this question is ......

Comment: As the title for "duplicite question" says **This question already has an answer here** and not **There is a same question here** we are really not looking for duplicite question but for question with answers that do answer this one! This question is marked right!

Comment: If there were other possibilities how well to do this and other possible answers, I wouln't consider closing this as the questions differ. But the decimate way is the fastes most efficient and the most correct.